# What is this famous quote?

Tags: rebus

What famous quote is portrayed by the rebus below?

The accepted answer will correctly explain every part.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> You must be the change you wish to see in the world.

Explanations:

> You (EWE)
>  Must (COMBUST - COB)
>  Be (BOWELS - OWLS)
>  The (POTHOLE - POOL)
>  Change (ARCHANGEL - AR - L)
>  You (LAYOUT - LAT)
>  Wish (WISHBONE - BONE)
>  To (TANGELO - ANGEL)
>  See (ROSELLE - ROLL)
>  In (ALIEN - ALE)
>  The (THIEF - I - F)
>  World (WONDERLAND - NDE - AN)

Comment: Bailey M...I had a feeling you would get it!

Comment: @JLee Glad to have that reputation :D

Comment: There are so many super hard puzzles on this site that fairly often I have the urge to make slightly easier puzzles to provide something for those who don't like their brains to hurt. Also, it's fun to create these rebuses.

Comment: @JLee I definitely appreciate them. It helps to have something nice and fun to take my mind off the ones that burn away at my brain cells. :) Keep up the great work!

Comment: Very nice! What makes this rebus stand out is the imaginative choices of word pictured. Rather than giving pieces of the word, the subtractions make a word fall out unexpectedly, giving a great moment of surprise and confirmation.